# Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted in ubuntu

Tags: flutter, android-studio, ubuntu, permissions, android-sdk-tools

I am install latest Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1 in ubuntu.
In this show error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
> platforms;android-33 Android SDK Platform 33
> build-tools;30.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3
> To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
> All licenses can be accepted using the sdkmanager command line tool:
> sdkmanager.bat --licenses
> Or, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#download-with-gradle

Using Android SDK: /usr/lib/android-sdk

I am trying to install all the sdk but error not gone.

[Logcate show log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS9Z7.png)

[SDK Plateforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czj5Q.png)

[SDK Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhnTV.png)

Comment: try this: flutter doctor --android-licenses

Comment: As @EricSu said, using "flutter doctor --android-licenses" should solve your problem. Run the command in the terminal and accept all the terms and conditions